# VBA to take screenshot and paste on ms word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA and have this requirement:
I have ms word open and I need a macro to take a screenshot of the window currently in focus and paste that screenshot on the word document already open.

I was trying something like this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)  

Sub TestDetails()                                                                                     
    Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25159988/11683

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the link doesn't hold the answer to the problem mentioned above.